# How can I reference a protocol instance variable from a protocol method?

Tags: swift, protocols

I have created a Swift package Example.  Inside Example.swift I have the following:

```
import Foundation

protocol Foo {
    var bar: String { get }
}

extension Foo {
    static func main() {
        print(bar)
    }
}

@main
struct Example: Foo {
    let bar = "Hello World"
}
```

I get the error `instance member 'bar' cannot be used on type 'Self'`.  How can I access a protocol member from within a protocol method ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with whether you are in a protocol method or not. You need an instance that conforms to `Foo`, e.g. an instance of `Example`, in order to access `bar`. There is no such instance in the static `main` method.

Comment: Perhaps you want to make `bar` static as well?

Comment: If I change `print(bar)` to `print("Hello World")` and recompile, the resulting binary when executed will print the string.  Instantiating the class is done by the package stuff, as far as I can tell.

Comment: No, "the package stuff", whatever that is, will not be instantiating your class. When your code is run, `Example.main()` is called, without creating an instance of `Example`. Notice that `main` is static so an instance is not needed.

Comment: Setting `bar` to static won't work; it generates errors like `candidate operates on an instance, not a type as required` which makes sense, because I'm trying to print the instance variable that is defined in the `Example` class.

Comment: Of course, I meant that you should also make the `bar` in `Example` static. But it seems like you are actually trying to print an instance property without having an instance? That is not possible.

Comment: I apologize for my imprecision with "the package" stuff.  I'm talking about `swift package init --type executable --name Example` and `swift build` here.  When I tried to instantiate the class, I got errors like `expressions are not allowed on the top level`.  Can you direct me to documentation that can help me instantiate something conforming to Foo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with whether you are in a protocol method or not. You need an instance of a type that conforms to `Foo`, e.g. an instance of `Example`, in order to access `bar`. There is no such instance in the static `main` method. In fact, you do not create any such instances in your entire program.

You can create an `Example` and access `foo` like this:

```
extension Foo {
    static func main() {
        print(Example().bar)
    }
}
```

But that kind of loses the point of having a protocol in the first place. I'm guessing you want whatever type `T` that conforms to `Foo` to have a `main` method that prints the `bar` that `T` declares, rather than always `Example.bar`.

In that case, you can require an additional initialiser in the protocol, giving you a way to create a new instance of whatever type it is that conforms to the protocol.

```
protocol Foo {
    var bar: String { get }
    
    init()
}

extension Foo {
    static func main() {
        // create an instance of myself, and access bar
        print(Self().bar)
    }
}
```

> Instantiating the class is done by the package stuff, as far as I can tell.

This is not true. The `@main` annotation just calls `Example.main()`. An instance is not, and does no need to be, created. Because `main` is static after all.

Comment: Adding the initializer to the protocol and including the `Self().` reference was what I needed.  Thank you for your help!